# Hosting a WCF service over internet with DNS

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service which work locally and within the network when used with the server name, this service needs to work on the internet to others outside the network to consume. I am currently hosting it on IIS. what will I need to make it available on the internet ? Do I need a DNS and SSL ? I am not sure what is required. Could somebody please let me know.

Comment: Assuming that you use HTTP-bindings, this is a very broad question, and it is mostly unrelated to WCF. So, try to search for more generic "how to make my web endpoint available in the Internet". At the minimum, you need a public IP address which will point to your machine with opened inbound connections, and that's it. DNS can be used to use domain names instead of IPs. SSL can be used for secure connection. Reverse proxy should also be considered. This question in general can only be covered by the full understanding of secure network architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web service is going to be open to the public, i.e. on the internet, then you will need a domain or at least have your IP mapped to a name in DNS accessible to the public, this would require that you are self hosting the sight on you own server and have a static IP address accessible outsite your network.

Typically you would run a DNS to map your web service's IP to a domain name. However if you are going through a hosting provider they will most likely do that part for you.

Anything public facing, I would recommend using SSL over HTTPS. If the service will only be accessible to certain people, then you could use several of the different types of authentication, certificates, username/password, or tokens. There are lots of things to consider like firewalls etc.

Here some maybe helpful links to get you started:

- [SSL in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl)
- [How do I host a wcf service on the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712778/how-do-i-host-a-wcf-service-on-the-internet)

Comment: Thank you so much for a clear explanation. I will try that and get back.